# How many GOOD numbers are there?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We call $x\in\mathbb{N}$ with the decimal representation $x=\overline{a_1a_2\ldots a_{k_x}}$ a GOOD  number if:

1. $x\geq 10$ ,
2. $a_1$ is even,
3. $a_2< a_3<a_4<\cdots<a_{k_x}$

For example, $4378$ and $6234689$ are GOOD numbers, whereas $156$ and $24673$ are not GOOD numbers. How many GOOD numbers are there?

Please give some idea/hints. I could not proceed, actually.

Comment: Nice question..

Comment: the question is interesting. have you tried

Comment: Hint: any set of distinct integers can be sorted in increasing order in exactly one way.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Each good number $x$ can be built from a choice of an even digit $a_1$ and a non-empty set of digits $\{a_2, \dots,  a_{k_x}\}$.

Example: If I give you $\color{blue}{4}$ as the even digit and $\{4,9,3\}$ as the rest of the digits, then your number has to be $\color{blue}{4}349$.